# Missing oil graphic

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Alright, I am completely tired of having to remember which tiles have oil because for some reason they never show up if they are on water or if some sort of improvement has been made on an oil land tile. There has to be some sort of fix made from a mod I just can't find it. If it helps I am playing on PC windows 7 64 bit direct-x 10 or 11, whatever the highest one is. I do not wish to use the Ctrl+r command as it may be a quick fix, but I want it fixed so I don't have to do that.

Thanks for the effort.

Comment: This occasionally happens to me, along with roads and certain other features not displaying. Reloading the game usually fixes the problem for me.

Comment: @studoku its only ever oil for me, and reloading does nothing

Comment: Do the oil icons show up in strategic view (F10 to toggle back and forth)?

Comment: @JamesCW yes they do

Comment: I had the same issue with Civ 5: Gods and Kings. Upgrading to BNW solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I notice that sometimes the game runs into a bug and tile texture stops rendering. If you save, quit and restart, it should come back, provided you're hitting the bug that I saw.

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Verify the integrity of the game cache in Steam.  If that doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling.